# ng-include: Include a file when part of the name is a angularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

On my javascript I have:

```
$scope.languages=[{lang:"en"},
                 {lang:"it"}
                 ];
```

I have two content file:
content/it/content.html
content/en/content.html

I want to load contents with ng-repeat according to my language.
This is what I've done:

```
<div ng-repeat="language in languages" lang={{language.lang}} ng-include src = "'content/'+{{language.lang}}+'/content.html'"></div>
```

The result I will expect in front-end is:

> This is my content in English
>
> This is my content in Italian

but id doesn't seem to work.

Could you tell me how I can include something when part of the name of the file is a angularJs directive?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Never mind. I found my solution by myself

```
<div ng-repeat="language in languages" lang={{language.lang}} ng-include src = "'content/'+language.lang+'/content.html'"></div>
```